# Replace comma separated master data with description in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are 2 SQL Server tables:

**Products**:

```
Name               Status Code
------------------------------------
Product 1          1001, 1003
Product 2          1001, 1005, 1006
```

**Status**:

```
Code               Description
------------------------------------
1001               State A
1003               State B
1005               State C
1006               State D
...
```

I wish to get something like:

```
Product          Status
---------------------------------------------
Product 1        State A, State B
Product 2        State A, State C, State D
```

Comment: Terrible data model.

Comment: The root of your problem is that you have delimited data in your tables. This is NOT how you should be handling data. It should be one row for each status code. Now you are struggling to retrieve data because the design is not normalized.

Comment: There are plenty of examples on how to parse delimited lists, and how to create them using SQL Server. On this site alone there are probably 1000's of answers and questions, many of the latter are probably marked as duplicates. What have you tried so far? What version of SQL Server are you using? The data model is wrong though, as Sean has stated. Ideally fix that issue, and the problem solves itself.

Comment: I know that the design is not as expected, but I can't change it.

Comment: Then you have to first split this mess into a normalized structure using a string splitter. Then you have squash it back together into the denormalized menace using STUFF and FOR XML.

Comment: Learn some database design.  Your current structure will give you nightmare later on.  Even now, things that are supposed to be a simple join become complicated because of the comma delimited column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like below:

<kbd>**[See working demo](http://rextester.com/ICI68882)**</kbd>

```
create table Products (Name varchar(100), [Status Code] varchar(100));
insert into Products values
('Product 1', '1001, 1003')
,('Product 2', '1001, 1005, 1006');
create table [Status] (Code varchar(100),      Description varchar(100));
insert into [Status] values
('1001',   'State A')
,('1003',   'State B')
,('1005',   'State C')
,('1006',   'State D')

; WITH X AS 
(
    SELECT 
     P1.Name,
     S.Description
    FROM
     (
     SELECT *,
     cast('<X>'+replace(P.[Status Code],',','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) AS xmlprods FROM Products P
     )P1
     CROSS APPLY
     ( 
     SELECT fdata.D.value('.','varchar(100)') AS splitdata 
     FROM P1.xmlprods.nodes('X') AS fdata(D)) O
     LEFT JOIN [Status] S
     ON S.Code=  LTRIM(RTRIM(O.splitdata ))
    ) 

SELECT 
    Name,
    Description= STUFF((
  SELECT ',' + Description FROM x AS x2 
  WHERE x2.Name = x.Name
  ORDER BY Name FOR XML PATH, 
  TYPE).value(N'.[1]',N'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
  FROM 
  X
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is answer. Works nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I used a temporary table but you can use any means you want

> SELECT    p.Product   , p.Status  , s.Description INTO #tmp FROM  (
>     SELECT  Name Product, TRIM(value ) Status   FROM tblProduct     CROSS
>   APPLY STRING_SPLIT(TRIM(StatusCode), ',') ) p JOIN tblStatus s ON
>   s.Code = p.Status
>
> select    distinct  Product
>       , stuff((
>           select ',' + tmp2.Description
>           from #tmp tmp2
>           where tmp2.Product = tmp1.Product
>           order by tmp2.Product
>           for xml path('')
>       ) ,1,1,'') as StatusCode   from #tmp tmp1 group by Product

Answer (score 0):

Below Query will help to make any comma separated to list.

```
SELECT A.OtherID, 
       Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Data
FROM 
(
    SELECT OtherID, 
           CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Data, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data 
    FROM  Table1
) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```