# Get individual values from comma seperated values in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with reference values and another table as selected reference values. In this table the selected reference value are comma separated. How can I get individual values from comma separated values?

```
CREATE TABLE [DBO].[TBL_REFERENCE] 
(
    /* REFERENCE TABLE */
     REF_ID BIGINT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
    ,REF_NUMBER INT NOT NULL
    ,REF_NAME NVARCHAR(20)
    ,REF_VALUE NVARCHAR(25)
    ,CONSTRAINT PK_REFERENCE PRIMARY KEY (REF_ID)
)

INSERT INTO TBL_REFERENCE (ref_number, ref_name, ref_value) 
VALUES (1, 'communication', 'mobile'),
       (1, 'communication', 'laptop'),
       (1, 'communication', 'PDA'),
       (1, 'communication', 'tabs'),
       (1, 'communication', 'iphone'),
       (1, 'communication', 'smart phone'),
       (1, 'communication', 'others');
```

Another table

```
CREATE TABLE [DBO].[TBL_FACILITY] 
(
    /* FACILITY TABLE */
     FACILITY_ID BIGINT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
    ,FAMILY_HEAD_ID BIGINT NOT NULL
    ,FACILITY_SELECTED INT --- REF_NAME
    ,FACILITY_USED NVARCHAR(25) --- ref_value
    ,CONSTRAINT PK_FACILITY PRIMARY KEY (FACILITY_ID)
    )   

INSERT INTO TBL_FACILITY (FAMILY_HEAD_ID, FACILITY_SELECTED, FACILITY_USED) 
VALUES (121, 1, '2,6'), (122, 1, '5'), (123, 1, '5,6');
```

The format of final result:

```
121 communication laptop
121 communication smart phone
122 communication iphone
123 communication iphone
123 communication smart phone
```

How can I get this result?

Comment: You should ***NOT*** store several values comma-separated into a single column. This is (a) a violation of the first normal-form of database design, and (b) a horribly bad design choice since it makes it impossible to create database-level foreign key constraints that ensure data integrity

Comment: Are you sure the values of all `tbl_reference.ref_number` columns' values are 1 or 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 as an identity column ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49615127/replace-comma-separated-master-data-with-description-in-a-column/49615766#49615766

Comment: http://rextester.com/BTPO68562

Answer (score 0):

Presuming ,as an identity column, `tbl_reference.ref_number` columns' values are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 in downwards order , by the contribution of `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` string operators, you may use the following SQL :

```
SELECT family_head_id, ref_name+' '+ref_value reference
  FROM TBL_FACILITY INNER JOIN TBL_REFERENCE 
    ON ( ref_number = SUBSTRING(facility_used,CHARINDEX(',', facility_used)-1,1) )
UNION ALL
SELECT family_head_id, ref_name+' '+ref_value reference
  FROM TBL_FACILITY INNER JOIN TBL_REFERENCE 
    ON ( ref_number = SUBSTRING(facility_used,CHARINDEX(',', facility_used)+1,1) )
 ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2158d/20)

Comment: If there's a data model with comma-seperated values you better expect more than two, e.g. `'1,2,3,4'` :-)